# How do reading apps such as Instapaper display huge amount of texts without using webview?

Tags: android, text, webview, textview

I once tried doing so with `TextView` inside `ScrollView` but it's just awful performance wise during initialization.

Comment: Use Android Studio's Layout Inspector, or `uiautomatorviewer`, and find out for yourself. Perhaps they use a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`. Perhaps they really do use a `WebView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I can only see my app's process on the layout inspector.

Comment: Ah, yes, that only works for debuggable processes. My apologies. `uiautomatorviewer` works for all apps.